# dynamicly add form fields in joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I'm wondering if there is a possibility to add form fields to depending on some options,

for example:

when user select number of options = 8 and user click save, on next view user see 8 text box each with different names.

I was trying to use form fields class not via `.xml` files but can't get it to work.

Any1 know if it is even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that's is possible. You can get the number of fields from the form. Assume It's 10(`$count`).

Next view you can loop as below and create text boxes.

```
for($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++)
 echo '<input type="text" name="fields[]" class="class_fields">';
```

At the backend you can fetch the data as below.

```
$values = JRequest::getVar( 'fields', 'default_values', 'post', 'array' );
```

[Read more](http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_and_Filtering_GET_and_POST_requests_with_JRequest%3a%3agetVar)

If you have any issues let me know

Comment: can i pass `$data` to for example: `JFormFieldList` not via `.xml` files ??

Comment: can you please explain a bit more? It's little bit unclear what you are asking here

Comment: i have data prepared for  `JFormFieldList` but don't know how to use it, i can't use any `.xml` file because option there are static and i want to add dynamic option i hope it clears a bit what i want.

Comment: here you will find set of function that you can use. http://docs.joomla.org/JFormFieldList/11.1. If you have issues let me know.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to add the list items dynamically you have to write your own JFormField like class and install in inside your component.

In your case you extend the JFormFieldList and override the getOptions() function. In .xml you use the new created input type name.

Here how to create and use new fields classes (start here): http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type

Next the example how to extend the JFormFieldList class: http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:How_to_add_custom_filters_to_components

In the second link for simplicity use (for example only)

```
public function getOptions()
    {
            // Initialize variables.
            $options = array(0=>"Option 0", 1=>"Option 1");


            return $options;
    }
```